# Cancel stream onData

Tags: dart

I have an event bus that handles all central events to my app. I have a special case where I have a sequence of asynchronous actions that I want to execute once only (when a special event happens), so I have to launch async function one, go through out of control other functions that will trigger an event for my second action, and so on.

So I need to launch action one, then listen to the event bus waiting for action one to trigger (undirectly) an event that will launch action two etc...

Naturally, once each element of the sequence is executed, I want to stop listening to the event that triggered it.

I imagined for that, a consumeOnce(event, action) function that will subscribe to the bus, wait for the expected event, execute the action when receiving the event and immediately cancel the subscription once the action launched (asynchronously)

```
  final StreamController<Map<PlaceParam, dynamic>> _controller =
  new StreamController<Map<PlaceParam, dynamic>>.broadcast();

  void consumeOnce(PlaceParam param, Function executeOnce) {
    StreamSubscription subscription = _controller.stream.listen((Map<PlaceParam, dynamic> params) {
      if(params.containsKey(param)) {
        executeOnce();
        subscription.cancel(); //can't access, too early: not created yet
      }
    });
  }
```

The issue is that I can't access the variable **subscription** in the body of my callback, since it is still not created at the time

Since nothing garanties that listeners will execute in their subscription order, I cannot register another subscriber who will remove my subscription (and even if the execution order was guaranteed, I will anyway find my self with a subscription that I can't remove : the one responsible for removing my original subscription)...

Any ideas please?

This pattern could solve my problem, but I don't find it elegant:

```
@Injectable()
class EventBus<K, V> {
  final StreamController<Map<PlaceParam, dynamic>> _controller =
  new StreamController<Map<PlaceParam, dynamic>>.broadcast();

  Future<Null> fire(Map<PlaceParam, dynamic> params) async {
    await _controller.add(params);
  }

  Stream<Map<PlaceParam, dynamic>> getBus() {
    return _controller.stream;
  }


  void consumeOnce(PlaceParam param, Function executeOnce) {
    SubscriptionRemover remover = new SubscriptionRemover(param, executeOnce);
    StreamSubscription subscription = _controller.stream.listen(remover.executeOnce);
    remover.subscription = subscription;
  }
}

class SubscriptionRemover {
  PlaceParam param;
  Function executeOnce;
  StreamSubscription subscription;

  SubscriptionRemover(this.param, this.executeOnce);

  void execute(Map<PlaceParam, dynamic> params) {
    if (params.containsKey(param)) {
      executeOnce();
      subscription.cancel();
    }
  }
}
```

But I don't like it much since theoretically, the event could happen between the two calls :

```
    StreamSubscription subscription = _controller.stream.listen(remover.executeOnce); //event may occur now!!!
    remover.subscription = subscription;
```

I think the existence of a method: _controller.stream.remove(Function fn) would have been a lot more direct and clear.

Am I right? or is there a way I didn't think of?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

> The issue is that I can't access the variable subscription in the body of my callback, since it is still not created at the time

That's correct - you cannot access is the `subscription` *variable*, even if you know that the subscription itself would exist. Dart doesn't allow variables declarations to refer to themselves. That's occasionally annoying when the variable it's only referenced inside a closure that won't be executed yet.

The solution is to either pre-declare the variable or to update the `onData`-listener after doing the listening:

```dart
    // Pre-declare variable (can't be final, and with null safety
    // it has to be late).
    late StreamSubscription<Map<PlaceParam, dynamic>> subscription;
    subscription = stream.listen((event) {
      .... subscription.cancel();
    });
```

or

```dart
    final subscription = stream.listen(null);
    subscription.onData((event) {  // Update onData after listening.
      .... subscription.cancel(); ....
    });
```

There can be cases where you can't access the subscription *object* yet, but that's only possible if the stream breaks the `Stream` contract and starts sending events immediately when it's listened to. Streams must not do that, they *must* wait until a later microtask before delivering the first event, so that the code that called `listen` has time to, say, receive the subscription and assign it to a variable. It's possible to violate the contract using a synchronous stream controller (which is one reason why synchronous stream controllers should be used judiciously).

(This answer provided was updated for null safety. Prior to Dart 2.12, the former proposal didn't need the `late`, and was generally the preferred approach. With Dart 2.12 and null safety, the latter approach will likely be better.)

Answer (score 18):

Just declare the variable beforehand, then you can access it from within the callback:

```
StreamSubscription subscription;
subscription = _controller.stream.listen((Map<PlaceParam, dynamic> params) {
  if(params.containsKey(param)) {
    executeOnce();
    subscription.cancel(); 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Callbacks that are only called once are gross. I think it would be more Dart-y to return a [`Future`](https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures):

```
Future<Null> consumeOnce(PlaceParam param) async {
  await _controller.stream.singleWhere((params) => params.containsKey(param));
}
```

Given that this is a one-liner I'm not sure it's even really necessary, unless it happens a lot. Clients of the EventBus could call `getBus().singleWhere` just as easily.

If you're really attached to the idea of using callbacks you can keep the `executeOnce` argument and invoke it after awaiting the call to `singleWhere`, but I can't really think of a situation where this would be better.

Comment: I'm subscribing to a stream already used by other consumers who consume more than once (that's in the question description)

Comment: I'm confused. Is there a case you are worried about where my solution wouldn't work?

Comment: You're right Collin, singleWhere() is a solution to listen only once. It's a good note : I was too focused on the subject of the question

Comment: The issue is that I need to listen to many events but only to one that corresponds to the condition if(params.containsKey(param))

Comment: @CollinJackson `firstWhere` would be a better choice as `singleWhere` completes the future either if stream is done or have a second element which satisfies the condition.

Answer (score 4):

As per the answer by Gunter. For null safety, use this code.

```
StreamSubscription? subscription;
subscription = _controller.stream.listen((Map<PlaceParam, dynamic> params) {
  if(params.containsKey(param)) {
    executeOnce();
    subscription?.cancel(); 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found!! was struggling for yesterday.

You can use this package for listening events throughout the app session.
https://pub.dev/packages/event_bus

Here is the example gist code for the same
https://gist.github.com/zahidshaikh08/85f96d68f7fcfeae658fc21c420ec60d

```
StreamSubscription? subscription;
final eventBus = EventBus();

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();

  /// initialize subscription
  subscription = eventBus.listenOnce((event) {

     /// check for your event type
     if (event is MyEvent) {
       var data = event.data;
     }
   });
}

@override
void dispose() {
   /// cancel subscription
   subscription?.cancel();
   super.dispose();
}

class MyEvent {
  MyData? data;

  MyEvent(this.data);
}

extension EventBusExt<T> on EventBus {

/// Safely listen messages for ONE TIME ONLY
StreamSubscription listenOnce(void Function(dynamic event) onData) => eventBus.streamController.stream.listen(onData);
  
}
```