# Dart - how to cancel a stream, mid stream

Tags: dart, stream, subscription

I'm trying to implement the equivalent of the linux head  command (and others) in dart.

This is part of a larger project I'm working on do replace bash with a dart shell.
You can see the work here:

https://pub.dev/packages/dshell

As such I'm working on a generic mechanism to read lines from a file.

The syntax I'm looking to implement looks like:

head('lines.txt', lines = 5, (line) => print(line));

Under the hood I've implemented a synchronous File class which provides a method to read lines.

My problem is that I'm using the  dart openRead method and converting it into a stream but I'm uncertain of the correct method of cancelling the subscription to the stream:

This is what I've tried:

```dart
  typedef bool CancelableLineAction(String line);

  void read(LineAction lineAction) {
    Stream<List<int>> inputStream = _file.openRead();

    var subscription = utf8.decoder
        .bind(inputStream)
        .transform(const LineSplitter())
        .listen((line) {

        if (lineAction(line) == false)
        {
            //
            // this line won't compile
            ///
            subscription.cancel();
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Of course the call to subscription.cancel() is invalid as subscription doesn't exist as yet.

So how do I cancel a subscription from within the listener?

The only thing I can think of is to have the listener throw an exception but this doesn't feel right.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cancel stream onData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450758/cancel-stream-ondata)

Comment: Yes that fixed the problem. I keep forgetting that dart is single threaded and as such there is no race conditions in most cases.